# Need to replace AVERAGEIFS formula for excel 2003

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

I've been trying to get to grips with excel formulae for days, and now have a spreadsheet with 140 cells, each with a slightly different formula. Unfortunately, it now needs to be 'dumbed down' to **Excel 2003**.
I've tried to get my head round array formulae, and `SUMPRODUCT`, but I'm getting bogged down.

Fresh eyes, anyone?

This is the formula I need to convert from 2010 to 2003:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Data!S:S,Data!L:L,"Atherstone",Data!T:T,"Service",Data!C:C,">="&K3,Data!C:C,"<="&K4)
```

`K3` is a date range start, with `K4` being the end, and `Data!` refers to `Sheet 2` where all the data is held.

(I know all my cell ranges will have to be explicit - i.e. C2:c65536).

Comment: You might find inspiration [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/413174-averageifs-excel-2003-a.html)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify your range as a fixed area, as it will not understand `S:S`.

your formula will end up looking something like this:

> =AVERAGE(IF(Data!L2:L2000="Atherstone",IF(Data!T2:T2000="Service",IF(Data!C2:C2000>=K3,IF(Data!C2:C2000<=K4,Data!S2:S2000)))))

*(Untested)*

you will also need to make it an **Array** formula, so excel can look at each of the values in the range individually by entering the formula using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, instead of the more usual <kbd>Enter</kbd> after you have finished typing everything